# How to insert class in function in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i want function that able to addchild the class that i want (and maybe set the X,Y,width,height,etc)

to put it simply i had movieclip class say x and y then i write

```
function addclass(theinputedclass:Class,nameofobject:String,otherparameter,etc...)
{
    var nameofobject:theinputedclass=new theinputedclass;
    addChild(nameofobject);
}
```

but as expected it does not working so how do you do it?

i have only little experience with c and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't right this:

```
var nameofobject:theinputedclass;
```

The compiler does not know this class. You should change it to:

```
var nameofobject:DisplayObject = new theinputedclass() as DisplayObject;
```

Comment: But since we're using addChild on the provided class, we can assume it must be AT LEAST a DisplayObject, and can speed up the AVM by letting the compiler know what type we're dealing with.  
`var nameOfObject : DisplayObject = new theInputedClass();`

Comment: Damn formatting doesn't do what I want it to do. Even the provided examples in the Markdown page doesn't work ;_;

Comment: @stalem ask for help in [stack meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) it can be accessed from top left corner of the screen